# Libgdx cursor disappears

Tags: libgdx, cursor, mouse

In my LibGdx game i am changin the cursor a lot. For example there are circles you can resize and the "resize cursor" must rotate. I have a .png for every 10°. It works but after playing with it for a while the cursor disappears. It reappears again, when I move the mouse outside the circle and set it back to Gdx.graphics.setSystemCursor(Cursor.SystemCursor.Arrow); But after that it gets invisible again, when setting a custom cursor(hovering over the circle). This is the code (simplified), I have in mouseMoved():

```
if(showResizeCursor) {
    Gdx.graphics.setCursor(Gdx.graphics.newCursor(
        resizeCursor(mousePos,center), 32, 32));
} else {        
    Gdx.graphics.setSystemCursor(Cursor.SystemCursor.Arrow);
}
```

The function resizeCursor() returns a Pixmap rotated in the right angle.

Comment: Does resizeCursor() rotate the same pixmap again and again or does it work on a "fresh" pixmap? Would be useful to see this function here.